# java program with Unirest is giving error

Tags: rest-api, java

I have a client id and client sercet , i want to invoke marketing cloud rest api to get access token

```
package TestingMC;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.*;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;

public class RestGetAccessToken {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken")
              .header("content-type", "application/json")
              .body("{\n    \"clientId\": \"ycmqXXXXXXXXXX1a3elu\",\n    \"clientSecret\": \"FHXXXXXXXXXXX8l8\"\n}")
              .asString();
    }

}
```

However this program is giving error on unirest line

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       The type HttpResponse is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments  at TestingMC.RestGetAccessToken.main(RestGetAccessToken.java:13)

any clue why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong HttpResponse class. Remove the following line of code from your source:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
```

And, optionally, add an import for the correct class:

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
```

(Since you're using a wildcard import, this is not strictly necessary, but recommended.)